# Fetch category subcategory in mysql from a single table

Tags: mysql, join

I have a table given below. I want to fetch all the category where parent is there.

```
id   name    parent
1    test1   0
2    test2   0
3    test3   1
4    test4   3
```

It should give the below result when I pass id = 4

```
test4 > test3 > test1

I try the below query: 

select a.* 
  from merchant_service_category a
     , merchant_service_category b 
 where a.id = b.parent
```

But it gives a generic result for overall table. I need only those records which have id = 4.
The query gives only 2 records test4 > test3 only.

Comment: MySQL does not support recursion 'out-of-the-box'. Choices include writing a sproc, joining the adjacency list to itself as often as could be required, switching to an alternative model (e.g. nested set), or handling the recursion logic in application level code.

Comment: @Strawberry, for what it's worth, MySQL is due to get recursive CTE queries in MySQL 8.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly, you want to fetch a record and with it his parent: a record which is in the same table. Therefore you need to join the result on the same table. Try this:

```
SELECT child.* FROM `merchant_service_category` child
JOIN `merchant_service_category` parent ON child.parent = parent.id
WHERE child.id = 4;
```

With this query, you fetch the record with id 4 and joining the result with his parent, category with ID 3.

Comment: This is useful for hierarchy with two levels only

Comment: Galago, it gives just 1 record where child.id is 4.

Comment: I need all those category till it reaches to parent 0. So, all the levels of the parent should be covered. The query should check if it has the parents, get it until it reaches to parent 0

Comment: Then I didn't understand your question. You want to return the record with ID 4 and with that the records of a lower parent ID while that ID isn't 0?

Answer (score -1):

I found the answer. Below is the query.

```
SELECT   T2.id,T2.name,T2.parent
FROM (
SELECT
    @r AS _id,
    (SELECT @r := parent FROM merchant_service_category WHERE id = _id) AS parent_id    FROM
    (SELECT @r := 4) vars,
    merchant_service_category h
WHERE @r <> 0) T1
JOIN merchant_service_category T2
ON T1._id = T2.id
```